# Django on AWS elastic beanstalk: failed to generate rsyslog file with error Procfile could not be parsed

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rsyslog, procfile

I am trying to add a custom Procfile to my Django elastic beanstalk environment but I am receiving the following error during the deploy:

> 022/06/02 08:14:22.827519 [INFO] Generating rsyslog config from Procfile

> 2022/06/02 08:14:22.827557 [ERROR] failed to generate rsyslog file with error Procfile could not  be parsed

> 2022/06/02 08:14:22.827564 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [GetToggleForceRotate]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to generate rsyslog file with error Procfile could not be parsed

The Procfile I am using is the following:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 --workers=1 --threads=10 myapp.wsgi:application
```

And the option I previously used in my .ebextentions configuration was

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: myapp.wsgi:application
    NumProcesses: 1
    NumThreads: 10
```

and it was running successfully. Any guess? Thank you

Comment: It seems like your `rsyslog.conf` has some errors. Use `rsyslogd -N1` to validate your config.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue, the issue was I had a comment at the beginning of my Procfile, removing that comment fixed it for me. Make sure your Procfile only contains the plain text command(s)

Comment: ty sir, saved me an hour on this one 

Comment: Glad to hear!!!

Comment: I found that I also had to remove a blank line from the start of the `Procfile` to get rid of this error.

Comment: Glad I found this. Worked perfectly after.

Comment: That is so ridiculous Amazon! Why can't a Procfile have comments! ‍♂️ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080834/can-a-procfile-have-comments